# Reading graph values from a text file in c

Tags: c, file, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to create a project about graphs and using BFS in c. But I have some problems from reading and also writing after when I fill the nodes from the command screen. If you can help about it I would be appreciated.

```
void createGraph(){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        for(j=0;j<100;j++){
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    i=0;j=0;
    while(1){
        printf("Enter the from n to vertices (Enter -1 to stop): ");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if(i == -1){
            return;
        }
        else{
            a[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can just enter the nodes from the command screen and do the works, so how can I open the file, print the edges and nodes to this file, and after that reading from it when I need.

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: I cannot create and read the FILE operations this part of the code

Comment: There are no FILE operations in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm) has a good explanation.

Just remember that calling `Sleep()` (or something similar) before closing the file will not save changes made to it. Also remember that if you open a file for writing, you can't read from it properly. You must first close the file, then open for reading.

Correct me if I'm wrong.